# JAVA IBrokers api

Tags: java, api, interactive-brokers

I use `reqHistoricalData()` method, but it doesn't return anything after call. Do I need additional method for handling data ?

This is my code

```
public void reqHistData (){
  // Create a new contract
  Contract contract = new com.ib.client.Contract();
  contract.symbol("USD");
  contract.secType("CASH");
  contract.currency("EUR");
  contract.exchange("IDEALPRO");

  api.client().reqHistoricalData(1, contract, "20140920 00:00:00", "1 D", "1 day", "TRADES", 0, 2, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call is asynchronous, meaning you have to wait for it to return data.  You do this by implementing the `EWrapper` interface and doing something with the returned data in the callback.  When creating the socket, you pass the wrapper for the callbacks.

This example will just print the results.

```
@Override
public void historicalData(int reqId, String date, double open, double high, double low, double close, int volume, int count, double WAP, boolean hasGaps) {
    System.out.println(EWrapperMsgGenerator.historicalData(reqId, date, open, high, low, close, volume, count, WAP, hasGaps));
}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere example or tutorial of this method execution, because it's kinda new thing for me and api documentation is not so clear ?

Comment: It looks like you're using the beta api, 9.72.  There is no documentation but it does come with a sample program.  The documentation is for version 9.71